# Script stops command in it with exit 0

Tags: bash, rhel, bash-script

When I write a bash script similar to this on RHEL 6,

```
if [ "$2" = "" ] ; then
    echo vip.start: ERROR: no NIC specified
    echo vip.start: Need IP and base interface name
    exit 1
fi
case "$1" in
    [0-9]*)
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo vip.start: ERROR: no IP address specified
        echo vip.start: Need IP and base interface name
        exit 1
        ;;
esac


# Is it already up?
#This uses the same algorithm as vip.stop
## If no conflicts, it should produce 'collisions:0
##=>For Solaris
#exists=`ifconfig -a | awk '
#$1 ~ /:/        {split($1,nic,":"); 
#                 lastif=sprintf("%s:%s",nic[1],nic[2]);}
#$2 == "'$1'"    { print lastif ; exit; }
#
#'`

##=> For Linux. Retreves IP Address
exists=$(ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr:$1" | awk '$1!="inet" && $1!="--" {print $1}')


if [ "$exists" = "" ] ; then
    ping -c 1 $1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "vip.start: ERROR: vip $1 already active elsewhere! Cannot continue!"
    exit 1
    fi
else
    echo vip.start: NOTICE: vip already exists, as $exists
    exit 0
fi

##=>This is fo Solaris
#ifconfig $2 addif $1 netmask + broadcast + up
##=>This is for generic GNU/Linux
echo "Bringing up VIP virtual interface"
ifconfig $2 $1 up
echo "VIP virtual interface has started"

exit 0
```

This script takes a command line argument like, `vip.start 192.168.1.1 eth0:1` and then is supposed to bring up the interface. When ran with `bash -x vip.start 192.168.1.1 eth0:1`, it shows that the interface comes up, but then doesn't appear when I issue an `ifconfig`. However, when I comment out the `exit 0` the VIP stays up and the script exits.

Comment: Strange, is there nothing else going on in your script _after_ the `exit` that gets executed if you comment it out? I cannot replicate this on my Debian.

Comment: Something else has to be going on that you aren't telling us. That aside, you do realize you're reinventing a mechanism that already exists in RHEL, right? Go into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, copy `ifcfg-eth0` to `ifcfg-eth0:1`, edit it to suit, and then `ifup eth0:1` will give your script's intended behavior.

Comment: I'll edit the post, and put the whole script up there.

Comment: The reason I don't do the configuration file is because this needs to be taken down real fast, then brought up on a second system in a HA cluster

Comment: Your HA-cluster has no method to handle service-IPs?

Comment: No, it uses shell scripts. This is the HA program, https://github.com/bolthole/freeha. I was toying around with it, and wanted to use it.